# Switch between "In Library" and "All Apple Music" in iTunes Search

Tags: itunes, apple-music

Is there a keyboard shortcut or hotkey to switch between the "In Library" tab and "All Apple Music" tab when searching in iTunes? From my research, the only way I see the ability to switch between tabs is by clicking them.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable All Controls in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts, then you can ⇥tab to the button and use space to select it. There does not seem to be a keyboard shortcut for toggling the option directly.

Comment: When I try to hit tab, the focus switches from the "Search" field to the "Back" button and I can't select the options using tab on macOS 10.14.4 with "All Controls" enabled. Does someone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

On a US keyboard, you can use `Command + Shift + [` and `Command + Shift + ]` to cycle among the tabs.

Here's an overview of [keyboard shortcuts for iTunes](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/keyboard-shortcuts-itns1019/mac).